# disputant vs disputer

Tags: differences, legalese

Any differences in meaning? [The dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dispute?q=dispute) doesn't explain. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disputer%2C+disputant&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisputer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisputant%3B%2Cc0)

> This dispute between the king and the estate of William Bankes, owner
>   of coastal land including Corfe Castle, concerned who had the best title to casks that had
>   washed ashore near Poole in Dorset. The court divided the casks between the **disputants**.

Source: P186, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

Comment: Could you present the results of your own research? This appears to be something which can be answered by a decent dictionary.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I've tried to differentiate them but see no explanation. Why did you close? What 'commonly-available reference answers this?

Comment: The question was closed because you had presented no research of your own. Now that you have (although a single dictionary isn't really enough since there are at least five online from reputable publishers), the question can be re-opened.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you for the elucidation. I'll keep links then in the future.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the intricacies of legalese, not about about English, and therefore should only be answered by an attorney.

Comment: @tchrist How'd this be legalese? I'm only asking about English here.

Comment: It’s legalese because any scintilla of distinction you are ever going to be able to weasel out of those two words is one that has no consequence to the English language or users thereof, only to a lawyer trying to twist words. Please consult an attorney.

Comment: @tchrist These two words can certainly be used in a sentence with no reference to law, so how do they have 'no consequence to the English language'? For example, am I a disputant or disputer here?

Comment: @LePressentiment Neither: you’re merely argumentative.

Comment: @tchrist How don't the two words have have 'no consequence to the English language'?

Comment: [Because they are virtually unused by real people](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disputant%2Cdisputer%2Ccomplainant%2Ccontestant%2Clawyer&year_start=1914&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisputant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisputer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomplainant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontestant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clawyer%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @tchrist What does 'contestant' mean there? That is a common word?

Comment: "off-topic" ? Why, attorneys avoid this site ? Or is it forbidden to them ?

Answer (score 1):

The functional meanings of *disputant* and *disputer* are extremely similar. According to Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003), a *disputant* is "one that is engaged in a dispute," whereas a *disputer* (listed but undefined in that dictionary) is presumably "one that disputes." Although neither definition is limited to participants in legal disputes, *disputant* is by far the more common term for such a participant.

Modifying the Ngram Viewer chart that tchrist provides in a comment above, we can see that *disputant* is also significantly more common than *disputer* in Ngram Book search results for the period from 1900 to 2000:

[image]

The preference for *disputant* over *disputer* in English is even more pronounced than the chart indicates because so many of the matches for *disputer* are to French texts. I checked the first 100 results for each term in each of the four main time periods that the Ngram Viewer divided the search results for 1900–2000 into. Of the 400 results for *disputant*, 8 were to books in which *disputant* appeared as a foreign word; of the 400 results for *disputer*, 184 were to books where *disputer* appeared as a foreign word. For the most recent time period (1994–2000), 42 of the first 100 reported matches for *disputer* were to French or German texts; in addition, some 25 supposed matches didn't report an actual match for the word, a ghosting phenomenon that plagues Google Book searches for words and phrases that have relatively few actual matches.

And finally, the legitimately English matches for *disputer* rely heavily on instances of translations of St. Paul's First Letter to the Corinthians that use the word *disputer*:

> Where is the wise? where is the scribe? where is the disputer of this world? hath not God made foolish the wisdom of the world?

For its part, *disputant* (as I noted earlier) appears many times in the context of legal writing, but it also appears in such nonlegal texts as Edward Gibbon’s *Decline and Fall of the Roman Empire*, John Aubrey’s *Brief Lives*, Emily Bronte’s *Wuthering Heights*, and John Ruskin’s “The Roots of Honour,” as well as in many other less famous works not dedicated to legal matters.

So if you're wondering which word is more common in nonlegalese English writing, the answer clearly is *disputant*. I can imagine using *disputer* instead of *disputant* in certain instances—such as where the dispute involves one person railing indiscriminately against the established order—but in situations involving disagreement and debate between opposed sides or individuals, I think *disputant* is much the better choice.